# ASP.NET Identity not recognizing logged in user as authenticated

Tags: asp.net, identity

I am having the following issue happening randomly and am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

My website is using Identity for logging in and the deny element in my application folder web.config to disallow unauthenticated users:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

99% of the time when a user logs in successfully they are allowed access to the applications start page BUT once in a while they are not allowed access and are returned instead to the sites home page which contains the "Login" link.  I can tell the application recognizes the user as logged in because they are not returned to the login page which is what happens if someone tries to directly access a page via the URL that requires authentication.  This is preventing users from accessing the application and the only thing that gets it working again is a restart of the web server at which point the logins work exactly as they should.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what could be happening here?

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: Note that when this happens it doesn't matter what user is trying to login, or what browser (IE Explorer, Chrome, Firefox).  It happens to all users on all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a [blog](http://moumitintech.blogspot.in/2015/08/basic-of-wifrole-based-authorization-in.html) in `basic of wif` .. which also contain a small 3 page project too with `web config` setting .. I hope this will help you..

Comment: Thanks but I'm not having a problem with roles but rather users randomly being denied access even though they are authenticated.

Comment: I think It is because every time the `authentication cookie` getting expired on browser .. make sure your `browser accept cookie`